# How to declare the type of the function const `f = ({ a = 0 } = {}) => a` in TS

Tags: typescript

I use type annotations in TS as some sort of documentation. For me, it is good to know the types my function will manage upfront.

I have not found a way to declare the type of this kind of function. The compiler infers a type, but when I try to annotate by my self with the same type, it crashes.

Take this function for example:

```
// compiler infers the type
// f: ({ a }?: { a?: number | undefined }) => number
const f = ({ a = 0 } = {}) => a;
```

But when I try to annotate it fails with the following error.

```
const f: ({ a }?: { a?: number | undefined }) => number =
    ({ a = 0 } = {}) => a;
//     ^
//     \-- Property 'a' does not exist on type '{ a?: number | undefined; } | undefined'
```

Comment: Okay, looks like this is a compiler bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does seem like a bug in the compiler, or at least an unfortunate limitation.  I haven't found an existing issue filed in GitHub about this particular situation; [microsoft/TypeScript#35160](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35160) seems to be related but doesn't quite answer how something like this can happen.  I have filed [microsoft/TypeScript#37271](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37271) to find out what's going on; I'll update here if I get more info.

UPDATE: This is a compiler bug that is fixed in `typescript@next` and will be released with TypeScript 3.9.1.  When that is released the answer here will just be "update your TS version".  For previous versions and for other interested parties, the rest of the answer remains.

---

But your question is how to annotate, so first let's make sure that the compiler isn't completely insane and that the type displayed when you hover over `f` really is compatible with it:

```
const f = ({ a = 0 } = {}) => a;

const g: ({ a }?: { a?: number; }) => number = f; // no error
```

That works.  So the problem must be that when you annotate `f` with its type explicitly, it provides a contextual type for the parameter which the compiler is unhappy with for some (possibly buggy) reason.  The workaround I can think of is to explicitly annotate this parameter:

```
const h: ({ a }?: { a?: number }) => number =
  ({ a = 0 }: { a?: number } = {}) => a; // no error
```

So that works.  It's odd that you'd need to annotate both the arrow function and its parameter, but at least you have a path forward.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZjAvDAFAbxgQyTADDAXxzQIEokA+LAbgFgAoB0SWAcwC5UNsCB+T7vxhgArgFsARgFMATtULlEVUZNk448gPSbhIGLJkgZDJuGgwAFp3RZCQwZxXSZCysPHOkDGF1vJ8BAJYQk5qRMgkilSYWjpgegZGJvQwQA)

Comment: Seems it should be fixed soon. This [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/37309) closes the issue you opened. You can play around with the nightly version [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=next#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgLhgCgN4wIYwL4H4nob4xgCuAtgEYCmATgNw4CUMAvAHwkU21sCwAKBgpCbGAAYcY1NhYdMjAPSKSIGHVohagoA). It did help!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you are saying correctly, you should be able to replace the `{ a }` with a variable name of your choosing:

```js
const f: (v?: {a?: number | undefined}) => number = ({ a = 0 } = {}) => a;
```

Because you are describing the shape of the argument in the annotation, you shouldn't need to specify that a is a member in the parameter declaration.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the problem persists. Try to compile this code.

Comment: What is it exactly that you are trying to accomplish with a function like that?  I ask only because I imagine that there is a much more clear, albeit more verbose way to accomplish it.